# Генератор чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Вот код, который выводит последовательность чисел Фибоначчи:

```
fib_range=[1, 1]
maximum = int(input("Enter the range for Fibbonachi's digits: "))
print("#1 - ", fib_range[0])
print("#2 - ", fib_range[1])
for iteration in range(2,maximum):
    fib_range.append(fib_range[iteration-2]+fib_range[iteration-1])
    print("#", iteration+1, " - ", fib_range[iteration])
```

Пытаюсь сделать более элегантное решение, но не получается, не хватает опыта. Пробовал сделать следующий генератор:

```
fib_range = [(fib_range[iteration-2] + fib_range[iteration-1) for iteration in range (2,maximum)]
```

Увы сколько не пробовал его изменять - выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто уже имеет огромный опыт в Python 3.x, как правильно оформить генератор для этого примера?

Answer (score 3):

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for __ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fib(10))          # Тест
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
> ```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно элегантно! Использование функции это отличное решение, а можно ли этот алгоритм упаковать в одну строчку, аналогично генератору, который я пытался сделать?

Comment: @SergeyRyabov, вы не пытались сделать *генератор*, а *рекурсивную функцию*. Может быть, что потому вы даже удивленный ответами, которые вы не хотели. То, что вы пытались сделать в одну строчку, называется *абстракция списка (list comprehension)* - он основан не на функциях, а на итеруемых объектах, как списки, множества, кортежи, итараторы, генераторы, и т. д. - Также, не возможно.

Comment: Увы сложности перевода, по этому я назвал list comprehension как генератор. Увы он и абстракцией списка тоже никак не называется. Однако в некоторых книгах используется название Генератор Списка, вот его и применил. В любом случае - спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/jgEIcY

```
def fib():
  a,b = 1,1
  while True:
    yield a
    a,b = b,a+b

import itertools

print(list(itertools.islice(fib(), 100)))
```

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881, 6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288, 44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994, 190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264, 806515533049393, 1304969544928657, 2111485077978050, 3416454622906707, 5527939700884757, 8944394323791464, 14472334024676221, 23416728348467685, 37889062373143906, 61305790721611591, 99194853094755497, 160500643816367088, 259695496911122585, 420196140727489673, 679891637638612258, 1100087778366101931, 1779979416004714189, 2880067194370816120, 4660046610375530309, 7540113804746346429, 12200160415121876738, 19740274219868223167, 31940434634990099905, 51680708854858323072, 83621143489848422977, 135301852344706746049, 218922995834555169026, 354224848179261915075]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный пример! А можно ли упаковать генератор в одну строчку, аналогичную, как в примере, только рабочую?

Comment: @СергейРябов, я не умею...